# Closing a popper MUI using ClickAwayListener affects everything inside

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, material-ui

I'm new react developer, here I have small problem my `ClickAwayListener` should close `Popper` when clicking 'x' or outside, which it does but problem is I have a component inside my `Paper` and that have `Select` when I click that select to see my options then options appear and fast disappear, I have tested and `ClickAwayListener` also affects this, how to disable the affect of `ClickAwayListener` to those inside `Paper`?

```js
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";

 const renderSettingsPopper = () => {
    return (
      <Popper
        id={"graph"}
        open={popupOpenState()}
        placement="left-start"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        className={props.classes.components}
        style={{ zIndex: 4 }}
        modifiers={{
          flip: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          preventOverflow: {
            enabled: true,
            boundariesElement: "viewport",
          },
        }}
      >
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={closeSettingsPopup}>
          <Paper className={props.classes.components}>
            {renderSettingsForm()}
          </Paper>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </Popper>
    );
  };
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is harder than I anticipated but I finally found a solution. You need to track the `Select` open state inside the `Popover`.

```
<Select
  label="Age"
  defaultValue={10}
  onOpen={() => setSelectOpen(true)}
  MenuProps={{
    TransitionProps: {
      onExited: () => setSelectOpen(false),
    },
  }}
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

And disable the close handler when one of the `Select` is currently opened:

```
<ClickAwayListener
  onClickAway={() => {
    if (selectOpen) return;
    handleClose();
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]